# Achieve 3D model using 2D horizontal polygons sorted by z-axis

Tags: c++, 3d

Please advise me.
I want to construct a 3D model in C++ using 2D horizontal polygons (actually a set of 2D points which form a closed contour) sorted by z-axis (Using frameworks like OpenGL).
How could I do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: What does "construct a 3D model" mean? You want to display it on the screen or just save it in a file?

Comment: This sounds a lot like a heightmap. You should be able to find implementations quickly.

Comment: I mean for displaying 3D model

Answer (score 0):

A 3D model usually consists of a vertice array and a triangles array. The vertices are your points where the order is irrelevant.
The triangles array then contains only indices from the vertice-array and describes the triangles that way.
For example if your points are pA, pB, pC and stored in that order in the vertices array, then your triangles array contains 0, 1, 2.

However the actual details depend a lot on your implementation environment. Look up some examples in your desired engine.

By the way, if this is for a research project or stuff like that, I'd recomend a higher level engine than OpenGL. I did a thesis project about code-generated 3D models project by using Unity. That's C# instead of C++, but unless you need large models to be created in Realtime, the speed suffices easily and you will develop much more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [DOOM engine](https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM/tree/master/linuxdoom-1.10) from id Software, in which they used a very similar principle to display 3D scenes. Also, take a look at the [Game Engine Black Book: DOOM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1099819776)

Briefly, the 2D polygons are converted into a *BSP tree* to create a set of convex nodes, which are then used for rendering. There are other resources for similar techniques, such as the [Build engine](https://github.com/fabiensanglard/vanilla_duke3D) which uses portal rendering.

Note that this technique you are trying to use has some limitations.